# angular2 date pipe locale_id period

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a problem with the angular2 date pipe when using danish locale.

When I format a date like:

```
{{myDate | date:'dd-MM-yyyy'}}
```

it outputs the day of the date with a suffixed period like this:

17.-03-2017

allthough I would expect it to be like this:

17-03-2017

The locale is set in the app.module like this:

```
providers: [ {provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'da-DK'} ]
```

I have made this plnkr to make it more clear  http://plnkr.co/edit/A5ddrKP5cmsSZ9bTqzPh

**UPDATE**

It probably has something to do with the way dates are formatted in danish. Se below:

```
var locale = 'da-DK'; 
var options = { weekday: 'long', year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' }; 
var date = new Date(2017,2,17); var result = new Intl.DateTimeFormat(locale, options).format(date); 
alert(result);
```

turns into --> fredag den 17. marts 2017

Notice the dot

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide all relevant code in an [mcve] in the question itself, not only on a third-party site.

Comment: Angular2 uses **Intl** for `dataPipe` internally https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl I think there is nothing to with angular2 here. See example https://jsfiddle.net/9jsnz0yL/ without angular2

Comment: Ok so it is not a problem with Angular2 then. If I change your fiddle to use sv-SE Intl.DateTimeFormat returns 17 without a dot. Do you know why Intl.DateTimeFormat return 17. and not just 17 if I use da-DK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

localization is "platform independent", ECMAscript provides specifications and each Javascript engine provides its own implementation.

There is also a compatibility implementation, [Intl.js](https://github.com/andyearnshaw/Intl.js), which will provide the API if it doesn't already exist. You can see the implementation for the locale Danish (Denmark) [here](https://github.com/andyearnshaw/Intl.js/blob/master/locale-data/json/da-DK.json), you will see the available formats, and the day always returns the period after.

```
 "availableFormats": {
                "d": "d.",
                "E": "ccc",
                "Ed": "E 'den' d.",
                "Ehm": "E h.mm a",
                "EHm": "E HH.mm",
                "Ehms": "E h.mm.ss a",
                "EHms": "E HH.mm.ss",
                "Gy": "y G",
                "GyMMM": "MMM y G",
                "GyMMMd": "d. MMM y G",
```

You could create a custom pipe, and chain it to remove the period

`{{myDate | date:'dd-MM-yyyy'|removePeriod}}`

```
@Pipe({name: 'removePeriod'})
    export class RemovePeriodPipe implements PipeTransform {
      transform(input: string) {
        return input.replace(/\./g, '');
      }
    }
```

Comment: That makes sense. I guess I will go for at removePeriod pipe or format the date like 'longFormat' --> '17. marts 2017' instead.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
{{ date | date:'ccc' | uppercase }}
```

Have a look at the official documentation: https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe

There you will find all format options.

Answer (score 0):

in module

```
import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';
import localeDk from '@angular/common/locales/da';
import { LOCALE_ID, NgModule } from '@angular/core';

registerLocaleData(localeDk);

@NgModule({...providers: [{ provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'da' }]})
```

in template

```
<div>{{ someAmountValue | currency: 'DKK':'kr.':'1.2-2' }}</div>
```

expected result `kr.` string is placed on the right side of the `someAmountValue`, like `40.521,00 kr.`